# Get method handle for overloaded method

Tags: java, java-7, methodhandle

Is it possible to look up a method handle for a overloaded method in Java 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a [`MethodHandle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html) to anything you can get a [`Method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) for using [`MethodHandles.Lookup.unreflect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#unreflect%28java.lang.reflect.Method%29).

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that one. Thanks!